# Нужно ли делать chrome.storage.local.set если я и так записываю значения в localStorage?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Это дублирующие строки кода или просто приоритетнее второй способ записи с вызовом конкретной функции? Или нужно оба фрагмента оставлять? Делаю расширение для Chrome.

```
localStorage.proxySetting = settings;

chrome.storage.local.set({
    'proxySetting': settings
  }, function() {});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если писать плагин для Chrome, то лучше конечно использовать второй вариант, так как он оптимизирован по сравнению с localStorage, подробнее почитайте [тут](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage)